# Ocean Shrink wrap modifier

Tags: shrinkwrap

The depth of my ocean doesn't deform with the surface when I applied the shrink wrap modifier (I use Blender 4.0.1).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello please show some screenshots or even share your file

Comment: It should work, of course your cube needs to be subdivided otherwise it won't adapt to the shape of the ocean, if it is already the case please share your file so that we can give a look

Comment: I can only upload image. How do I share the file please?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use another platform like workupload